# Javascript Textfield as an Effective Captcha

Tags: javascript, captcha, textfield

I've learned that the majority of spambots can't read client-side javascript. Only users can. This is a fact I have researched and experienced.

So, to me, this means that if you put a single javascript textfield on your form that users have to fill out, this can be quite an effective captcha.

My question is...

1. What are the drawbacks to a javascript textfield?
2. How hard is it to create and execute a javascript textfield?
3. Can it be styled in a way that's uniform with the other non-javascript textfields on your form?

Comment: Bot creator loads your page in browser. Submits form. Looks at form fields. Duplicates. In the end, you are submitting the same form fields. This can be easily replicated. Using a CAPTCHA will allow you to *verify* a user much better than using a field that someone could easily duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the user has JS disabled the textarea won't work (probably a very small minority, but that depends on your app.) You also suddenly have content in JS (should ideally always be in HTML). No huge drawbacks really.
2. It's simple to create a textarea with JS, working with the DOM.
3. Yes